# Can I turn of Pylance for certain file names? (_NotebookConcat_ Interactive Files)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylance

Pylance is giving me a bunch of error messages in vscode in my IPython Interactive terminal. Is there a way to disallow these `_NotebookConcat_` files from Pylance's search purview?

[image: This is only a small portion of the errors]

Comment: Sorry, but could you provide a full screenshot of it?